# Menu-bar in responsive design disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a responsive design template where the horizontal menu-bar will convert into an icon to save space. Basically I have created 3 media queries, i.e. > 800px, betweeen 500 to 800px and less than 500px. 
.

It is working fine, but when the windowWidth of the screen reaches the range of 484px to 500px, the menu-bar just disappears! You can go to the link to view the test page : http://www.acetraining.com.sg/responsive1/

```
// JavaScript Document
var windowSize = "";
var windowWidth = 0;
var actualSize = 0;

$(document).ready(function (e) {
    checkBrowserSize();
    setInterval("checkBrowserSize()", 100);


    $("a.mobile_menu").on("click", function () {
        var navHeight = $("nav").height();//finding current height of navigation
        var newNavHeight = $("nav div").height();

        //mobile screen
        if (navHeight == 0) {
            $("nav").animate({"height": newNavHeight + "px"}, 500);
            $(this).addClass("selected");
        }
        //retract back to 0
        else {
            $("nav").animate({"height": "0px"}, 500);
            $(this).removeClass("selected");
        }
    });

});

function checkBrowserSize() {
    windowWidth = window.outerWidth;
    var contentWidth = $("body").width();
    var sizeDiff = windowWidth - contentWidth;//size of scrollbar
    actualSize = windowWidth - sizeDiff;

    if (actualSize > 800) {
        newWindowSize = "large";
    }
    if (actualSize <= 800 && actualSize > 500) {
        newWindowSize = "medium";
    }
    if (actualSize <= 500) {
        newWindowSize = "small";
    }
    //display out
    $("h1").html(windowWidth + "(" + contentWidth + "(contentWidth) + " + sizeDiff + "(sizeDiff)) is " + newWindowSize);

    if (windowSize != newWindowSize) {
        windowSize = newWindowSize;
        //invoke changeNav
        changeNav();
    }
    else {
     //append the word no change
        $("h1").append("--no change--");
    }
}//end of checkBrowserSize()

function changeNav() {
    if (windowSize == "large") {
        $("nav").css("height", "auto");
    }
    else if (windowSize == "medium") {
        $("nav").css("height", "auto");
    }
    else if (windowSize == "small") {
        $("nav").css("height", "0px");
        $("a.mobile_menu").removeClass("selected");//load in the first image of the mobile     menu when you resize to small 
    }
}//end of changeNav()
```

I suspect the problem lies in my javascript file. I have attached the codes for your perusal:

I am hoping there is a way to show the menus between these ranges.

Answer (score 0):

The media query in screen_layout_large.css css file is hiding the mobile menu. Either edit the media query to give a min-width or show the mobile menu as follows in changeNav function.

```
function changeNav() {
    if (windowSize == "large") {
        $("nav").css("height", "auto");
    }
    else if (windowSize == "medium") {
        $("nav").css("height", "auto");
    }
    else if (windowSize == "small") {
        $("nav").css("height", "0px");
        $("a.mobile_menu").show().removeClass("selected");//load in the first image of the mobile     menu when you resize to small 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply.

Sorry I don't quite get you. My screen_layout_large.css responsibility is to hide the menu from all screen sizes. The only code found in the screen_layout_large.css is :

    /*hide mobile menu from all screen sizes*/
    a.mobile_menu{
 display:none;
    }  

Even though I have commented that out, the problem still persists that the menu disappears between the range of 484px to 500px. 

Strange.

Comment: Adding the `.show()` didn't worked? `$("a.mobile_menu").show().removeClass("selected");`

Comment: Right now, I couldn't replicate the issue. Seems like you have changed something and it fixed the issue.